# Вычислить члены последовательности через рекурсию

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Дана последовательной, в которой

```
b>1
a1 = b
a2 = (a1 - 1)/sqrt(2)
a3 = (a2 - 1)/sqrt(3)
a4 = (a3 - 1)/sqrt(4)
и так далее
```

Как правильно решить задачу через рекурсию. Я сделал так, но функция в не работает. Помогите разобраться что не так и правильно ли я вообще понял рекурсию

```js
function sequenceRight(b,maxIndex){ 
    if( maxIndex != 1){
        return (sequenceRight(b, maxIndex - 1) - 1 ) / Math.sqrt(maxIndex);
    }
    else{
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем выражается "не работает"?

Comment: Вычисляется только одно выражение с ответом -0.478.......

Comment: А что должно быть?

Comment: число со знаком - не может быть,  и по заданию должно вычисляться до тех пор пока maxIndex станет 1

Comment: Самый очевидный случай - если b равно 0, то будет со знаком минус. Оно и вычисляется пока maxIndex не станет 1.

Comment: Для конкретики в условии задачи b >1

Comment: function sequenceRight(b,maxIndex){ 
 if( maxIndex == 1){
  return b;
 }
 else{
  return (sequenceRight(b, maxIndex - 1) - 1 ) / Math.sqrt(maxIndex);
 }
}

Comment: Ок. Пусть 2. Тогда все члены последовательности, начиная с а3, будут отрицательными.  Чем больше b, тем больше положительных членов, но рано или поздно они станут отрицательными.

Comment: Но почему функция возращает только один член последовательности

Comment: Так и должно быть. Если вы хотите получить все значения от 0 до n, то нужно или вызывать ее в цикле.

Comment: Точно, спасибо большое. Я совсем ступил. Просто там было ещё задание применить шаблон мемоизации и когда я делал это с функцией вычисляющей последовательность в цикле у меня возникала ошибка. Я всё понял,  возможно просто уже запутался. Спасибо большое